# Persist ip route and ip rule configurations for Policy Based Routing (iproute2)

Tags: centos, fedora, networkmanager, iproute, nmcli

Currently running on Fedora Server 23, I've been searching for the right way to persist commands such as:

```
ip route add default via 10.0.2.1 dev ens32 table EXAMPLE_TABLE
ip rule add from 10.1.2.50 lookup EXAMPLE_TABLE prio 1000
```

either through nmcli (ideally) or through some other, similarly, **sane** way.

I've seen examples like lodging it on the *route-ifname* file but that don't seem to execute the default rule correctly.

If you run `ip route show table EXAMPLE_TABLE` after a reboot you'll realize it doesn't stick - at least in my experience.

Any insights into this would be lovely, thank you.

Comment: My recollection is that every line in `route-(device)` will generate a `ip route add (contents of line here)` and every line in `rule-(device)` will generate a `ip rule add (contents of line here)`, but it's possible that NetworkManager has different ideas.

Comment: Sadly the route-(device) file seems to completely ignore the table parameter. :(

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I know of to persist the default route is to add the default route destination to the `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-<device>` file as the value for GATEWAY. This creates that default route every time that interface is brought up, the other routes are persisted through the `route-<device>` files in the same directory.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work if you are using policy based routing...

Answer (score 0):

The `rules` to be preserved should be placed in:

```
/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/rule-lo
```

The `routes` to be preserved should be placed in:

```
/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route-lo
```

You will have noticed that I am suggesting to use rule-**lo** and route-**lo** files regardless of which device you are saving the respective config for, as if the rules and routes were for the loopback interface. Some time ago, I observed on CentOS 7.8 possibly the same issue you are observing here, where PBR rules saved in their respective correct device files were being ignored, but all the rules saved in the *-**lo** were honoured. I wish I could shed more light on the reasons as to why that was the case, but I didn't investigate further at the time. Some logs were pointing to the NetworkManager-dispatcher being responsible for this.

For completeness of the answer, the routing tables are identified by their table numbers. If you want to refer to a routing table by a name, a name mapping must be created. E.g. to refer to the table number 100 by the name "EXAMPLE_TABLE":

```
echo '100 EXAMPLE_TABLE' | sudo tee -a /etc/iproute2/rt_tables
```